# SQLAlchemy: Unsure if DB Setup Correctly

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've attempted to set up my DB in Python using SQLAlchemy.  I have a Player class like so:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,  rating, college, ranking = None, firstName = None, lastName = None):
        self.rating = rating
        self.college = college
        self.ranking = ranking
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
```

Then I have a few DB-specific methods in a module called databaseFunctions.py:

```
#if player exists, update his rating and ranking; otherwise, add new object to DB
def updateSpecificDBEntry(playerObject, session):
    #find player in DB with firstName and lastName
    currentPlayer = session.query(Player).filter(firstName == playerObject.firstName).filter(playerObject.lastName == lastName).first()
    #set rating = newRating
    if currentPlayer.count():
        currentPlayer.rating = playerObject.rating
        currentPlayer.ranking = playerObject.ranking
    else:
        addEntryToDB(playerObject, session)

def updateEntireDB(arrayOfPlayerObjects, session):
    for player in arrayOfPlayerObjects:
        updateSpecificDBEntry(player, session)
```

My main method is very basic:

```
def main():
    #create engine (for use by base and session)
    engine = databaseFunctions.createEngine()
    #create session
    session = databaseFunctions.createSession(engine)
    #get all players from CSA website
    allPlayers = getSortedGender(constants.mainURL, constants.menTeams)
    databaseFunctions.updateEntireDB(allPlayers, session)
    databaseFunctions.findPlayerWithRanking(100, session)
```

A couple questions:

1) I'm getting an error on the last function call.  Here's the error message:

```
  File "helpfulFunctions.py", line 116, in <module>
    main()
  File "helpfulFunctions.py", line 108, in main
    databaseFunctions.updateEntireDB(allPlayers, session)
  File "/Users/benjaminclayman/Desktop/SquashScraper/databaseFunctions.py", line 42, in updateEntireDB
    updateSpecificDBEntry(player, session)
  File "/Users/benjaminclayman/Desktop/SquashScraper/databaseFunctions.py", line 34, in updateSpecificDBEntry
    if currentPlayer.count():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'
```

SQLAlchemy doesn't like my use of if `currentPlayer.count()`, where `currentPlayer` is the object returned from my SQLAlchemy query.  I'm pretty confused because I've looked through the documentation and SQLAlchemy *does* have a `count()` method:

[image]

2) I'm trying to find the player object in my DB that has a ranking of 100.  But it looks like my query is returning the None object (as `currentPlayer`) which is very surprising.  I'm obviously doing something incorrectly.

I basically scrape all the players, make them into Player objects, sort them and then loop through and give his correct ranking.  Then I add all of them to the database using the below methods.  So there *should* be a player with ranking 100 in the database (there are ~650 players that get scraped).

Any idea what is going on here?

Thanks for the help,
bclayman

Edited to show example of SQL generated by my code:

```
2015-06-16 20:05:33,664 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('Lilliian A.', 'Wacker', 1, 0)
2015-06-16 20:05:33,666 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO players ("firstName", "lastName", college, ranking, rating) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2015-06-16 20:05:33,666 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (652, 'Lilliian A.', 'Boston University', 'Wacker', 2.51)
2015-06-16 20:05:33,667 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2015-06-16 20:05:33,669 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2015-06-16 20:05:33,670 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT players.id AS players_id, players."firstName" AS "players_firstName", players."lastName" AS "players_lastName", players.college AS players_college, players.ranking AS players_ranking, players.rating AS players_rating
FROM players
WHERE players."firstName" = ? AND players."lastName" = ?
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

It looks like this part:

2015-06-16 20:05:33,666 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO players ("firstName", "lastName", college, ranking, rating) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

may not be inserting anything into the players table...

Ideas?

Comment: Is this intended to use SQLAlchemy's Declarative ORM? If so, there are several components missing here, and you should follow the [Object Relational Tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html) to get set up properly. Additionally, your query is returning `None` for `currentPlayer` which causes the error you're seeing. If it didn't, though, you'd have an instance of a model (because you call `first()`) rather than a `Query` object. The `Query` object is what has `count`, not the individual model instances.

Comment: @jonafato Yes, it's supposed to be following that.  Edited original post to add example of SQL generated by my code

Comment: @jonafato Do you see anything missing aside from creating a Base using declarative_base()?  Still not clear to me what this does / what it gets me (even after looking over the tutorial)

Comment: Based on your stack trace, your code isn't getting to the point of querying player 100. It's failing on `currentPlayer.count()` because `currentPlayer` is `None`. You should just be checking `if currentPlayer:` here, since `first` returns the first row it finds matching the query or `None` of no rows are found.

Comment: I see that there's a new question with the `if currentPlayer.count():` -> `if currentPlayer:` edit. Is this question resolved?

Comment: @jonafato First question resolved, second question not